# Regex for all illegal filename characters before filetype extension

Tags: regex, character, filenames

I'm looking for a Regex that exchanges all illegal filename chars like () space . etc before the filetype ending like .jpg by an -

i got:
[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+
matches every illegal filename char, but including file extension
and
.*(?=.)
matching everything until the last occurence of .

how do i combine these?

one of my evil file names is
(800x800-png)MGC1000-03EPTD-021_RAL7035-5010.tif.png

after regex replace it should look like
-800x800-png-MGC1000-03EPTD-021_RAL7035-5010-tif.png

the regex should be working in libre office / excel search and replace.

thanks for your help!

Comment: `.*(?=.)` matches everything but the last character. You mean `.*(?=\.)`.

Comment: You need to define which characters are "illegal". On most UNIX-like systems, all characters other than `'/'` and `'\0'` are valid in file names (but many characters will cause problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` and use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that the string ends with a dot and 1+ word characters.

In the replacement use a hyphen `-`

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?=.*\.\w+$)
```

As per comment from [@Stein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106275/stein) you might shorten it to:

```
[^\w-]+(?=.*\.\w+$)
```

**Explanation**

- `[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` Match 1+ times any character that is not in the character class
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `.*\.\w+` Match any character 0+ times, then a dot and 1+ word chars
  - `$` Assert the end of the string
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I0e3fu/1)

If the extension itself could have special characters, then you might update `\w+$` to `[^.\s]+$` like:

```
[^\w-]+(?=.*\.[^.\s]+$)
```

Comment: super close to what i need, thank you guys! i would have never got it to work...even after years of occasional regex usage. the last one 

`[^\w-]+(?=.*\.[^.\s]+$)`

works perfectly in regextester...unfortunately not in libre office. any idea how to get that expression to work in there without having to use a 2nd txt editor with regex?

Comment: @ff-webdesigner I have tested this expression in LibreOffice Calc and Writer on Ubuntu and it seems to work for me. Just to be sure, did you check the `Regular expressions` checkbox? So if you say it does not work you mean nothing happens? or does it replace too much? This is a screenshot of how I tested it https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI3fx.png

Comment: thanks 4th bird. i did use reguiar expressions checkbox. just forgot to deactivate "diacritic sensitive" and set "replace in": values instead of formula. perfect match!!!